# How does JPA Handle Commits when Runtime Exceptions Occur

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

I'm using Hibernate implementation of JPA in my web application that is persisting to a Oracle DBMS.  If I have a service method that inserts some data that uses the Spring declarative transaction annotation (@Transaction), when does the change get committed to the DBMS?  If I have thousands of threads inserting data using this service method and the server crashes (something like OutOfMemory Exception) what will happen to the transactions that have been inserted but not committed?  Does it differ from JDBC?

Comment: In the end, the Spring transaction is handled by the database, whatever API you use to access the database. And anyway, Hibernate uses JDBC to access the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically commit happen before EntityManager is closed (at the end of method decorated with `@Transaction` if the caller is not decored). If using hibernate/JPA you can debug transaction begin/commits/rollback by setting following logger into DEBUG:

```
org.hibernate.transaction=DEBUG 
org.hibernate.engine.transaction=DEBUG # Hibernate 4.2.2 or higher
```

Normally when runtime exception occur your transaction will be rolled back, but it depends your configuration/setup.